# List of WiFi networks missing in 22.10

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm running 22.10 GNOME (beta) with stock kernel and recently ran into an issue, seemingly after a few updates.

The list of WiFi networks in GNOME Settings is empty. It shows that it's scanning but no networks ever appear.

Temporarily connected using an eth cable to be able to post this.

WiFi in this system worked before. Also I can dual boot into Windows - WiFi is fine. I also tried booting 22.04 from a USB drive - WiFi is fine too.

`nmcli d` shows this:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enp3s0  ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
wlo1    wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

I can scan like this `sudo iw dev wlo1 scan` and it comes up with the expected list of (many) networks.

My hardware is an Intel Z690 motherboard with buit-in WiFi. Based on `iw scan` working, the driver is getting loaded and the hw is recognized by the kernel.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

Update:

I tried to connect using `iw` but got this error:

```
sudo iwconfig wlo1 essid ...my ssid... key s:...my password...
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device wlo1 ; Invalid argument.
```

So looks like something *is* wrong, why the "invalid argument"?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: The [*beta* was only just released](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/30/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-final-beta-released/)... we're in the stage where testing is requested so that bugs can be found & reported, so thank you for testing, but this isn't a bug tracker.  Please refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Ubuntu 22.10 is in the process of switching from wpa_supplicant to iwd.

On my machine, service `iwd` was masked and service `wpa_supplicant` was enabled and running.

In addtion, `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/iwd.conf` contained `wifi.backend=iwd`.

To summarize, NetworkManager was set up to use `iwd` but `iwd` was not running.

My solution:

I tried to unmask / enable / start iwd and restart NetworkManager but that did not help.

Going the opposite route did work:

I re-enabled wpa_supplicant, commented out the `wifi.backend=iwd`, and restarted NetworkManager. My WiFi networks immediately showed in GNOME settings.

Comment: The same happened to me! I was recommended to setup iwd backend to avoid wifi getting disconnected unexpectedly, did not know why iwd was not working